# Identifying boundary of double integral after change of variables

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral

$$
 \int_{2b}^\Lambda dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x^2-4b^2}} dy f(x^2-y^2)
$$

that I know is convergent, for any $b>0, x>0, \Lambda > 2b$.

I wanted to perform this integral by using the following change of variables

$$
x= r \cosh{\theta}\,,\qquad y= r \sinh{\theta}
$$

The Jacobian of this transformation is $1/2$. Then,
$$
 \int_{2b}^\Lambda dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x^2-4b^2}} dy  = \frac{1}{2}\int d\theta \int_{4b^2}^{\Lambda^2} d r
$$

What troubles me is how to determine the region of integration of $\theta$. Notice that the function $f(x^2-y^2)$ doesn't depend on $\theta$, so I thought the integration with respect to $\theta$ will give me just a function depending on $\Lambda$ and $b$.

How do I do this change of variables?

Comment: Just a few points, the Jacobian and the notation for the order of integration doesn't make sense. As written, the Jacobian should be $r$ not $\frac{1}{2}$ and the $dy$ integral should be inside as it is performed first. Naturally this also affects the bounds for $r$ you found later.

Comment: @NinadMunshi sorry, this is the problem of being a physicist :P let me edit the question

Comment: It looks like you are posting bits and pieces of the same calculation as different questions, would you be interested in posting your full query and calculation in a separate post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral gets you the area bounded by the hyperboloid on its side, the $x$ axis and the line $x=\Lambda$. In order to find the bounds in the new coordinate system, we will have to transform each boundary separately

$$\begin{cases}x^2-y^2 = 4b^2 \\ y = 0 \\ x=\Lambda \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}r = + 2b \\ \theta = 0 \\ r = \Lambda\operatorname{sech}\theta\end{cases}$$

Unlike regular polar coordinates, $r$ *can* and *must* be negative at times, thus specifying the positive root is absolutely crucial. The Jacobian, likewise, is given by

$$\left|\begin{vmatrix}\cosh\theta & r\sinh \theta \\ \sinh\theta & r\cosh\theta\end{vmatrix}\right| = |r\cosh^2\theta-r\sinh^2\theta| = |r|$$

Thus the integral can be written one of two ways

$$\int_{2b}^\Lambda\int_0^{\operatorname{sech}^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{\Lambda}\right)}rf(r^2)\:d\theta\:dr$$

$$\int_0^{\operatorname{sech}^{-1}\left(\frac{2b}{\Lambda}\right)} \int_{2b}^{\Lambda\operatorname{sech}\theta}rf(r^2)\:dr\:d\theta$$

Neither of which is an integral just between constants.

Comment: I am very sorry, I have been too quick in writing the question - I had to be more careful. The actual change of coordinates I am considering is $x = \sqrt{r}\cosh{\theta}, y = \sqrt{r}\sinh{\theta}$. If you delete your answer, i will edit my question accordingly and I will let you answer then. Sorry again

Comment: @apt45 it's not a big deal - notice that the integrands are already of the form $\frac{1}{2}d(r^2)$ it's a two second edit to the equations at the very end since it doesn't matter whether we do the change of variable all at once or in a chain. If you could just mention what the original change of variable you had in the post was, that would be appreciated.